# Laravel 5 blade shows a blank page when there is error instead of throwing exception

Tags: php, exception, laravel, view, laravel-blade

In laravel 4 when you try to render a view that does not exists in **app\views** or a view with undefined variables laravel will throw an exception or show error that helps with debug.

I have a fresh installation of laravel 5.0.13 and am having a tough time troubleshooting a blade template that shows a blank page when i render a view that does not exists instead or a template with undefined variables instead of throwing an exception or error which will clue me in when debug.

I have installed filp/whoops:~1.0. but still recieve a blank page

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('indexx'); //this view does not really exist
    }
}
```

The file **indexx** does not exist in my **resources/views** and i expect Laravel to throw an exception but am getting a blank page instead, why?

Also when i render a view that exists with some undefined variables i simply get a blank page

Example:

class ProfileController extends Controller
{

```
    public function index()
    {
        return view('index'); //this view exists
    }
```

}

The content of resources/views/index

```
{!! $this_variable_was_not_passed_an_I_expect_error !!}
```

As you can see in the view file above the variable does not exist by laravel will simply show a blank page instead of throwing an exception or some debug error.

Also to note i change my laravel default view in config/views

```
'paths' => [ 
//realpath(base_path('resources/views')) 
realpath(base_path('resources/themes/default')) 
],
```

And laravel was able to render views from resources/themes/default as long as there is no error in the template however, if any error was encountered such ar undefined variable a laravel displays a blank page instead of showing error message

Also to mention that I install virtual box and vagrant on window 7

**Could this be a bug or something? Please assist.**

Comment: Please add, that you've changed your view folder to your question!

Comment: Are you doing this on Linux? If so, note Laravel caches it's views in the storage directory. Change the perms to 755 for the directory. I've had to do this myself.

Comment: i installed vagrant and virtual box on window 7.

Comment: Taylor Orwell is releasing homestead support on VMWare tomorrow. i think virtualbox and vagrant is also complicating things. I might end up doing a fresh installation of laravel 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know why this happened but its now working as required after i run

`vagrant destroy` to destroy homestead VM

and then `vagrant up` - to create the VM

The error messages has now showing up instead of blank page:

[image]

Comment: In my Case what happen is that: Exceptions/Handler.php not found & because of that exception handler class does not exist it was throwing an 500 error all time.
Solution:  php artisan optimize or composer install

Answer (score 7):

Try to change permission on the storage folder:

```
chmod -R 0777 storage
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution which helped me, is running

```
composer install
```

I deployed with git which auto ignores some files. running composer install fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem but here comes the reason and the solution:
The logfiles in storage/logs needs to be owned/writable by the webserver user. Otherwise L5 gives you a blank page.

I run "php artisan ..." always as root. If an exception was thrown and Laravel creates a new logfile, then it's owned by root. On my Debian i run in the project root folder:

`chown www-data.root * -R`

to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

//lavarel 4
* Add this to app/start/gobal.php

```
App::error(function(Exception $e, $code) {
            $runner = new \Whoops\Run;
            $inspect = new \Whoops\Exception\Inspector($e);
            $handler = new \Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler;
            $handler->setRun($run);
            $handler->setInspector($insp);
            $handler->setException($e);
            return $handler->handle($e);
});
```

//lavarel 5
* Add this to app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
 public function render($request, Exception $exception)
 {
    ..........
            $runner = new \Whoops\Run;
            $inspect = new \Whoops\Exception\Inspector($e);
            $handler = new \Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler;
            $handler->setRun($run);
            $handler->setInspector($insp);
            $handler->setException($e);
            $handler->handle($e);
     ......
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```