# Set up Laravel 5 on Apache VirtualHost

Tags: php, macos, apache, virtualhost, laravel-5

For the last week I've been setting up my development environment on my new MacBook using Homebrew.
So far everything went great, but I'm stumped when it comes to Laravel 5.

During my last semester at school I intensively worked in Laravel 4 and I knew how to set it up properly to serve from the public folder using Apache instead of the php artisan serve command.
I modified the Apache configs to point the DocumentRoot to the L4 public folder and changed the paths in index.php to match that. I can't seem to find out how to do this properly in L5 and not break any functionality.
This seems to have changed quite a bit in Laravel 5.

I'm running a VirtualHost configuration on my Apache setup and am using dnsmasq to enable usage of .dev domains, so I can do things like www.wordpress.dev and www.junk.dev which point to localhost/wordpress and localhost/junk respectively.

So my goal is to serve Laravel 5 from the public folder using VirtualHosts and assign it to the virtual domain name www.laravel.dev. Currently this gives me a blank page. 
Can anybody help me set this up correctly?

My httpd-vhosts.conf is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin ******@***.com
   DocumentRoot "/Server/laravel/public"
   ServerName laravel.dev
   ServerAlias www.laravel.dev
   ErrorLog "/Server/logs/laravel_log"
   CustomLog "/Server/logs/laravel_custom_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And public/index.php is unmodified (not that I didn't try to modify it...).
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first check the webserver logs and the Laravel logfile in /Server/laravel/storage/logs/.
The blank page smells like the same problem as here: [Laravel 5 blade shows a blank page when there is error instead of throwing exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877913/)

Comment: Well, the last few entries in the log file when into Console are:

`::1 - - [28/Mar/2015:20:47:33 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2015:20:47:34 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [28/Mar/2015:20:47:37 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
::1 - - [28/Mar/2015:20:47:42 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -`
No 404 errors seem to be thrown. The site did work, by the way, but I think that was after I ran php artisan serve and closed that process again, just to check if that side worked ok. Perhaps some sort of caching made it work. But I'll take a look at the link.

Comment: Well, checking the log files did help out in the end. Adding `Options +FollowSymlinks` did the trick for me and things are running smoothly as far as I can see. Editing config/app.php with this entry helped out a lot too:  `'log' => 'errorlog',`

Comment: I've found a simple solution:

    `sudo chown -R <your_apache_user> . && sudo chmod -R 775 .`

Altough, I don't know if this is a good idea, in terms of security.